Should I systematically mention my PI in the acknowledgements?
Assume you are a postdoc funded by Prof. X (PI) and publish a paper with Prof. Y but Prof. X is not an author. Should Prof. X be systematically mentioned in the acknowledgements ?

Yes, it would be very appropriate for you to mention them as they provided the funding that made the work possible.
In other situations it is likely obvious from your affiliation where the enabling funding comes from, but not in this one. It is beyond polite, probably necessary.

No, this is not strictly necessary.
It is typically necessary to acknowledge the funding that has made the work possible when this is not obvious from your affiliation. This often takes the for of a line like "This work was funded by (name of funding agency)'s (name of grant) grant number XXXXX." There is many possible (more verbose) variants, but in my experience it is not particularly common for this to mention the PI of the grant by name.
Of course, if the PI has provided some sort of feedback on the work, it could be very appropriate to acknowledge them for that.
In any case, the correct course of action is to ask Prof. X how your funding should be acknowledged. They will likely provide you with a sentence to include with all the correct grant numbers etc. If they insist on being named in that sentence, go with that.

But don't imply in acknowledging a grant funding source that YOU got the grant if it was your professor, rather than being indirectly funded through your professor. So, I disagree just a bit with this, though not "strictly" necessary is a judgement call.

In some journals/fields it's common to be explicit about who funding went through (i.e., the PI), usually with initials. In others it's becoming common to include all funding in a conflict of interest section, even from government and institutional sources.

@BryanKrause It is not surprising that there are field dependent differences here. In my field, I have yet to find examples of the PI of a grant being acknowledged.
